# How to handle keydown Event in asp.net Textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textbox in web form(asp.net). when user already keyin data, then they will press Enter key, so that the data will be update to database.

Is there any way possible to perform this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on _" when user already keyin data"_? In general, you cannot handle the clientside `keydown`-event on serverside. But you can handle the `TextChanged` event which is raised when the text was changed and the `TextBox` lost focus(you need to set `AutoPostBack` to true if you want  it to be reaised immediately).

Comment: Isn't pressing `Enter` once a form has been filled out the same as clicking/actioning a "Submit" button for the form in question?

Comment: what I mean is that When user  already typed information, they want to update to textbox. they want to have a single click (Enter Key) to do update operation.

Comment: lukeHennerley, you are right. That is what user want. How could I do so ?

Comment: Do you need solution with Jquery or only javascript?

Comment: In any solution, I appreciate ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function InitTextBox() {
//var _txt = $('#<%= txt.ClientID%>'); or
var _txt = $('input:[id*="txtId"]');
if (_txt.length < 1) return;
_txt.get(0).autocomplete = 'off';
_txt.on('keydown', function (evt) {
    var _self = $(this);
    event = evt ? evt : window.event;
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        if ($.browser.msie)
        { event.cancelBubble = true; event.returnValue = false; }
        else { event.preventDefault(); }
        if (_self.val().length > 0 && _self.val().match(/^\s*$/) == null)
            __doPostBack(_self.attr('name'), '');
    }
});
}
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(InitTextBox);
```

And set autopostback for textbox to false, please

Answer (score 1):

Dino Esposito had [wrote about this a while back](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/aspnet2/hit-enter-and-post-back-123595).  You wouldn't necessarily need a custom control, but can use his JavaScript.

If you have a control wrapped around a Panel, and you have the DefaultButtonID property set, the panel will trigger a postback on enter too by clicking the desired button specified by the ID.  That's another way.