# Call Server Side function with Keyup Event in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a TextBox and I want to capture the `Keyup` in the Textbox and get the TextBox value at the Code Behind File and Bind The GridView with the Input Received from the TextBox.

I don't want to use `Text_Change` Event of Asp.net. i want that when ever user enter anything in the TextBox, that value should go to code behind and bind the grid by calling `BindGrid` Function

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

protected void BindGrid(string searchvalue)
{    
    //  i want the txtSearch value over here.    
}
```

Comment: Do you need somthing like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803569/how-to-handle-keydown-event-in-asp-net-textbox/13804562#13804562 If Yes I can remake it for your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use asp.net ajax. Putting your button and grid in [**UpdatePanel**](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/updatepaneloverview.aspx) will update the gridview after binding on button click.

*In html*

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatePanel">
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="search"  
                ClientIDMode="Static" OnKeyUp="refreshPanel(this);" />
```

*In javascript*

```
function refreshPanel(textbox) {
     alert(this.value)
    __doPostBack('<%= updatePanel.UniqueID %>', this.value);
}
```

*In code behind*

```
 string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
```

Comment: how will it perform the action with Key Up ?

Comment: and i dont have any button.i want to perform the action with keyup event

Comment: Check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249152/how-to-trigger-an-updatepanel-by-a-textbox-control

Comment: and how will i pass my values to my function ?